# Defining Variable-size input data for Matlab Coder

Tags: matlab, mex, matlab-coder

I'm trying to generate a mex code file from the .m file using Matlab coder. The code for which is

```
function [result,x]=tesrank(A,x)

result = [];
n = x;
for col= 1:n
   result = [result, sum(A==col, 2)];
end
```

For fixed size, I'm able to get it using

```
codegen tesrank -args {zeros(2,3), zeros(1)}
% Here size(A)=2x3 and size(x)=1x1
```

How do I do it without limiting the size of A and x?

Comment: When I try to execute code generation for this function, it fails. Could you verify?

Comment: You can do this kind of coding for arbitrary sizes of A and x as long as you give an upper bound to their sizes. See documentation pointed to by user2987828.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to limit the size of the array A.

Check this example (using Matlab 2014a):

```
codegen('funcAccumarray1D_max.m', ...
    '-report', ...
    '-args', {coder.typeof(double(0), [Inf 1]), ...
              coder.typeof(double(0), [Inf 1])}, ...
    '-o', 'funcAccumarray1D_max')
```

for this function:

```
function [ outs ] = funcAccumarray1D_max(subs, vals, sz) 
%FUNCACCUMARRAY1D_MAX Construct an array by accumulation using 'max'
%#codegen
outs = NaN(sz, 1, 'like', vals);
for ix=1:size(subs,1)
  sub = subs(ix);
  outs(sub,1) = max(outs(sub,1), vals(ix,1));
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For building, the function `coder.typeof` is your friend here.  To do what you want, which is to have variables that allow unbounded dimensions, you would declare your input arguments this way:

```
codegen tesrank -args {coder.typeof(0, [Inf, Inf]), coder.typeof(0, [1, Inf])}
```

In my example, A is completely unbounded in two dimensions (you can have more than two, just increase the length of the size array to typeof) and x is bounded in the first dimension to a size of 1 exactly, but unbounded in the second dimension. Looking at your code, you may not want x unbounded, but if you do, that's how you do it.

There are more capabilities of coder.typeof you could explore.

Answer (score -1):

You can't, according to page p7-15 and p25-24 of Mathworks' [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/coder/coder_ug.pdf).